# How to get the count of a type conforming to `Sequence`?

Tags: swift, count, sequence

Let's say I have this code:

```
func work<S: Sequence>(sequence: S) {
    // do stuff
}
```

How could I figure out how many elements there are in `sequence`?
The obvious version I'd go for is pretty inefficient:

```
var count = 0
for element in sequence {
    count += 1
}
```

There must be a nicer way, right?

Comment: warning: Depending on the implementation of the `Sequence` it might be empty after you do this counting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think that there is a  better method for an *arbitrary* type conforming to
`SequenceType`. The only thing that is known about a sequence is that
is has a `generate()` method returning a `GeneratorType`, which in turn
has a `next()` method. The `next()` method advances to the next
element of the sequence and returns it, or returns `nil` if there
is no next element.

Note that it is not required at all that `next()` eventually returns
`nil`: a sequence may have "infinite" elements.

Therefore enumerating the sequence is the only method to count its
elements. But this need not terminate. Therefore the answer could
also be: *A function taking a sequence argument should not need to know
the total number of elements.*

For types conforming to `CollectionType` you can use the
`countElements()` function (renamed to `count()` in Swift 1.2).

There is also `underestimateCount()`:

```
/// Return an underestimate of the number of elements in the given
/// sequence, without consuming the sequence.  For Sequences that are
/// actually Collections, this will return countElements(x)
func underestimateCount<T : SequenceType>(x: T) -> Int
```

but that does not necessarily return the exact number of elements.

Comment: Will `underestimateCount` return a count greater than, or less than the actual count?

Comment: @MarcusRossel: An underestimate is always *less or equal* to the actual value. For arbitrary sequences, it might just be zero, so it is probably useless.

Comment: That is indeed useless in my case.

Comment: @MarcusRossel: Yes, I just wanted to mention it. I think that the real answer is *"the function should not need to know the number of elements of the sequence"* (or it should take a collection type or an array as argument).

Comment: When implementing a version using `CollectionType` I get a return value of `C.Index.Distance`. How do I convert the return value to an `Int`?

Comment: @MarcusRossel: Good question. It seems that for most (all?) concrete collections, Index.Distance is actually an Int, so you could declare your function as `func myfunc<C: CollectionType where C.Index.Distance == Int>(coll : C)`. Or you just take an array as argument. Otherwise I am running out of ideas, and it is too late in the evening. Perhaps you just ask another question :)

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda late - I'll try your solution tomorrow :D

Comment: is this for real? I have to count all the elements myself or is there some new thing now for swift 3 or 4? Or is this one of those "iOS Devs obviously don't need this duuh" principles?

Comment: @SaikCaskey: A sequence need not be finite (example: `let seq = sequence(first: 0, next: { $0 + 1})`), and the elements can be computed lazily, so there is no way to determine its "count" (which may be "infinite") without *consuming* the sequence.   – Things are different for `Collection` which has a `count` property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. What do iOS devs use infinite sequences for?

Comment: @SaikCaskey: An example: If `fib` is the "infinite" sequence of all Fibonacci numbers, then `let sum = fib.prefix(while: { $0 < 1000 }).reduce(0, +)` is the sum of all Fibonacci numbers below 1000.

Comment: I understand Sequence comprehension and that Swift is simply offering that kind of structure, excellent for Swift. What I do not understand is the why this is useful in a mobile context. What use cases are there for the infinite sequences in Swift, or, indeed, any mobile development? Obviously you were giving me a contrived example, but the thought that this property needs to be part of swift so that you can get the first 1000 of Fibonacci is frankly ludicrous

Comment: @SaikCaskey: Swift is a general-purpose language, not only for mobile development.

Answer (score 4):

A more "functional" approach would be:

```
let count = sequence.reduce(0) { acc, row in acc + 1 }
```

Or even make an extension:

```
extension Sequence {
    var count: Int { return reduce(0) { acc, row in acc + 1 } }
}

let count = sequence.count
```

**Note** This does still suffer from the basic sequence problem that you have to consume the sequence to count it.