# Swift Collection underestimateCount usage

Tags: ios, swift, collections

I wonder, what is the use case for Collection `underestimateCount`? [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641232-underestimatedcount) says that it has the same complexity as standard Collection [count](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1782861-count).

```
/// Returns a value less than or equal to the number of elements in
/// `self`, *nondestructively*.
///
/// - Complexity: O(N).
public func underestimateCount() -> Int
```

But it doesn't describe when it should be used and for what reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one retrieve the element-count of a type conforming to \`SequenceType\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752743/how-does-one-retrieve-the-element-count-of-a-type-conforming-to-sequencetype). The answer in the linked Q&A describes that counting some `Sequence`:s need us to iteratively make use of its generator (swift 3: iterator). Using the iterator to explicitly count the number of elements will in some cases actually consume the sequence, in so destroying it. `underestimateCount()` promises to return a count that is not larger than the actual one.

Comment: ... and as also described in the answer, `underestimateCount()` for sequences that are collections will in fact return the actual count.

Comment: @dfri This question is different, and moreover this answer DOESN'T  answer my question while Hamish does. Similar subject != Identical.

Comment: Hence the _"possible duplicate ..."_. Its always good to link Q&A:s that are duplicate "enough" (I believe the _answer_ to you question lies within the _answer_ of the dupe target, but that fact is that the target is somewhat outdated), as it will be easier to find an answer to any of the two questions. Note that I also added an answer for this very reason (dupe out of date).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`underestimatedCount` is actually a requirement of the `Sequence` protocol, and has [a default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L994) that just returns `0`:

```
public var underestimatedCount: Int {
  return 0
}
```

However, for sequences that provide their own implementation of `underestimatedCount`, this can be useful for logic that needs a lower bound of how long the sequence is, without having to iterate through it (remember that `Sequence` gives no guarantee of non-destructive iteration).

For example, the `map(_:)` method on `Sequence` ([see its implementation here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L797)) uses `underestimateCount` in order to reserve an initial capacity for the resultant array:

```
  public func map<T>(
    _ transform: (Iterator.Element) throws -> T
  ) rethrows -> [T] {

    let initialCapacity = underestimatedCount
    var result = ContiguousArray<T>()
    result.reserveCapacity(initialCapacity) 

    // ...
```

This allows `map(_:)` to minimise the cost of repeatedly appending to the `result`, as an initial block of memory has (possibly) already been allocated for it (although its worth noting in any case that `ContiguousArray` has an exponential growth strategy that amortises the cost of appending).

However, in the case of a `Collection`, [the default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1212) of `underestimateCount` actually just returns the collection's `count`:

```
public var underestimatedCount: Int {
    // TODO: swift-3-indexing-model - review the following
  return numericCast(count)
}
```

Which will be an O(1) operation for collections that conform to `RandomAccessCollection`, O(n) otherwise.

Therefore, because of this default implementation, using a `Collection`'s `underestimatedCount` directly is definitely less common than using a `Sequence`'s, as `Collection` guarantees non-destructive iteration, and in most cases `underestimatedCount` will just return the `count`.

Although, of course, custom collection types could provide their own implementation of `underestimatedCount` – giving a lower bound of how many elements they contain, in a possibly more efficient way than their `count` implementation, which could potentially be useful.

Answer (score 4):

*(Since the duplicate target I've suggested is somewhat outdated)*

In Swift 3, the method `underestimateCount()` has been replaced by the computed property `underestimatedCount`. We can have a look at the source code for the [implementation of the latter for `Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift):

> ```
>   /// A value less than or equal to the number of elements in the collection.
>   ///
>   /// - Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to
>   ///   `RandomAccessCollection`; otherwise, O(*n*), where *n* is the length
>   ///   of the collection.
>   public var underestimatedCount: Int {
>     // TODO: swift-3-indexing-model - review the following
>     return numericCast(count)
>   }
>
>   /// The number of elements in the collection.
>   ///
>   /// - Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to
>   ///   `RandomAccessCollection`; otherwise, O(*n*), where *n* is the length
>   ///   of the collection.
>   public var count: IndexDistance {
>     return distance(from: startIndex, to: endIndex)
>   }
> ```

Its apparent that `underestimatedCount` simply makes use of `count` for types conforming to `Collection` (unless these types implements their own version of `underestimatedCount`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't tell me why would I use it (by implementing this on my own).

Comment: @KlimczakM for a `Collection` (which you specifically ask for in your question), I naturally don't see any technical difference between the default implementations of `count` and `underestimatedCount` (except for the numeric cast), but you could naturally make use of the semantics of `underestimatedCount` to implement your own version of it (for some custom collection), where you could allow yourself to actually return a count that is not guaranteed to be the actual one (if this would ever turn out to be useful for your custom collection).

Comment: ... but I believe the interesting use case for `underestimatedCount` is for types that are sequences (but not collection), especially with the new [`sequence` functions](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/func/sequence/) that can be used to generate a stream-like sequence that is not, necessarily, finite. For custom sequences of yours, `underestimatedCount` could naturally have useful applications (non-consuming count).